# JavaFX how to jump to adjacent timelines?

Tags: java, javafx

`Timelines` is a collections initialized as

```
List<Timeline> timelines = new ArrayList<>();
```

the value of each `timeline` (element of `timelines`) is a short tweet. A snippet about constructions of each `timeline`, note every `timeline` come with a `KeyFrame`

```
// offset is adjusted according to msg length
Text tweet = new Text(offset, displayHeight - 15, tweetBody);

// set timeline
Timeline ti= new Timeline();
ti.setCycleCount(1);
ti.setAutoReverse(false);
// stop at a place where users cannot see
KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(tweet.xProperty(),-10 - mesLength); 
// playtime is defined according to msg length
KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(playtime), kv); 
tl.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
timelines.add(ti);
```

Suppose in total we have 10 tweets. Build 10 of above timelines iteratively, chain them with proper X-positions (i.e. tweet1: offset 800, tweet2: offset  1800, tweet3: offset 2500 etc) and durations, run all timelines the same time. That is, all tweets are initialized out of view.

For example, in this picture you have all tweets initialized but they are out of view.[image]

Click `Run`[image]

Messages kick in [image]

First message ends second message begins [image]

What I am playing:

```
timelines.forEach(Animation::play)
```

How to switch to adjacent tweets in `timelines` using `Next` and `Previous` menuItem.

```
MenuItem nextControl = new MenuItem("Next");
fasterControl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // I want to use jumpTo but didn't figure it out
        // timelines.forEach(timeline -> timeline.jumpTo(Duration.));
    }
});
```

One extra question, once the tweets got running, how to reset the window back to empty.[image]

If there needs for clarification and/or code, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean, you switch to different tweet in the timeline? Are you saying you want a specific tweet to have a specific position, but the timeline continues scrolling?

Comment: All of tweets are chained in some order through `timeline`,I am playing the collection `timelines`: `timelines.forEach(Animation::play)`. I want to switch from current tweet to its neighbours using `next`  and `previous`.

Comment: What happens when you "switch tweet"?

Comment: I don't understand why you have more than one timeline. It seems like you would have one timeline with all of your keyframes. Then when you want to go to a specific time/location you could use `jumpTo`. Maybe you could create a small example, using some random strings instead of tweets.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't make sense to me either having more than one timeline, unfortunately, those many timelines are given and I was asked to make operations with them. If there's more than one timeline, `jumpTo` cannot be applied, right?

Comment: I cannot conceive what is happening. It looks like all of the messages just slide out of view...at the same time. Can you whip up a working example? (or a broken example that compiles)

Comment: Exactly! All messages are initalized out of view and when hit play these messages will slide in.

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is changing one property. Save a List,

```
 List<Text> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then have a field/variable representing your current text.

```
 Text current;
```

No on handle, you find your current index, and grab it's timeline.

```
 public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      if(current!=null){
          TimeLine tl = timeLines.get(0);
          current = tweets.get(0);

          tl.stop();
          tl.getKeyFrames().clear();
          //set the display values eg the x value to zero.
          tl.play();

      } else{
          int index = tweets.indexOf(current);
          TimeLine oldLine = timeLines.get(index);
          //stop the timeline, clear the old keyframes.
          //create a new keyvalue, keyframe that hides this text, and play the timeline.

          index = (index+1)%tweets.size();
          TimeLine line = timeLines.get(index);
          current = tweets.get(index);
          //create a new keyvale/keyframe that shows this text, and play the time line.
      }
}
```